# How to append a specific element in a sub_list (list inside a list) as a new element in this sub_list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have developed this code, and want to search for a specific word and put it in a sub_list as an element with other two elements.

```
Key_word = 'Project Name'
output = ['try to find this element','element2','element3','i also try to find that']
mssg =''
mssg2 = ''
sub_list = []
list =[]
for line in output: #output is a list with few elements inside it
    if not mssg and re.search('try to find', line):
        sub_list.append(line)
        continue 
    if Key_word in line:
        sub_list.append(mssg) 
        list.append(sub_list)
        mssg = ''
        mail_and_mssg = []
    if 'i also try' in line:
        sub_list.append(mssg2) #append the commit message
        list.append(sub_list)
        mssg2 = ''
        sub_list = []
    else:
        mssg = '{} {}'.format(mssg, line)
```

what i get is:

```
[['elementA','elementB'],[elementC]]
```

but what i want to get is

```
[['elementA','elementB','elementC']]
```

How can i get this last form, please?

Comment: why do you need such a data structure as `sub_list` ? a simple list or a dict should be better.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Mt intention from this code is that i want to have one sub_list to include some related information like this [['Name1', 'email1', 'address1'], ['Name2', 'email2', 'address2']] so i want to put each related set of information in one list. Any suggestions to do it better way?

Answer (score 0):

Same question as KaiserKatze above - Why do you need a structure with "sub_list" instead of an ordinary list?

Anyways to answer your question, realise how you can access `['elementA', 'elementB']` by `mail_and_mssg[0]`. Therefore to append to it, simply write

```
mail_and_mssg[0].append(mssg2)
```

(Again, you should reconsider your code's functionality and simplify everything as much as possible. Similar to in maths, you won't write 1+(2*3). )

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
Mt intention from this code is that i want to have one sub_list to include some related information like this
[['Name1', 'email1', 'address1'], ['Name2', 'email2', 'address2']]

so i want to put each related set of information in one list. Any suggestions to do it better way?

Comment: @johnadam It would be better if each "information set" is stored in a dictionary, such as `mail_and_mssg[0]` can be `{"name": "john", "email": "test@gmail.com", "address": "..."}` etc. This way, it is easy to expand with more information. Other than that, I suppose your approach right now is fine.